# Dynamically add RealtimeDatabaseTriggers

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is it possible to dynamically add RealtimeDatabaseTriggers?
In my use case, I need to add (and remove) new RealtimeDatabaseTriggers as a result of previous write operation.

Docs state only how to add triggers on functions deployment (via exports)
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.  Deploying a Cloud Function is a somewhat resource intensive process, so it would not be scalable to define new functions "on the fly" like this.  All of your logic that handles an event *must* be in place prior to the event being triggered.